# Android Custom LinearLayout and inflating xml

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view, layout-inflater

I have an `xml` layout that when inflated into a `View` object, the layout displays as expected. However, I created a custom `LinearLayout` class, and inflate the `xml` layout when creating an instance of the class by using

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.icon_item, this, true);
```

in the constructor. I am not setting any `LayoutParams` or anything on the custom `LinearLayout` class, and when I try to display the custom class, it seems there are some weird margins placed that cut off some of the text in the layout inside.

I want to know if there is any way to set the custom `LinearLayout` so it has no effects on the layout xml, but just acts as an invisible container. I thought setting "attachToRoot" to true when inflating would solve this, but didn't work as expected.

Comment: An image with the problem or , even better, some code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When using `inflate(..)` with attachToRoot = true, this is the equivalent of physically placing the XML inside the ViewGroup like so:

```
<LinearLayout ..>
  <TextView .. />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also meaning that when being `measure`'d and laid out by the `LinearLayout` it will inherit any layout properties imposed in your xml layout you are inflating.

So if you `<TextView..>` contains `android:layout_margin="8dp"` or `padding` for example then your `CustomLinearLayout` will also layout the view using these `Layout` properties.

I would post more code if you want me to fix/create a better solution for you.